# Karma: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading src/node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js

Tags: node.js, angular, karma-runner

I'm using angular2-seed from https://github.com/angular/quickstart. I want to run a unit test for one of my classes. Below is my test:

```
describe('my method', () => {
    it('should expect true', () => {
        mockContextSettings = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockContextSettings', ['environment']);
        mockWindow = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockWindow', ['location']);
        workContext = new WorkContext(mockContextSettings, mockWindow);
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The test will run correctly without

```
workContext = new WorkContext(mockContextSettings, mockWindow);
```

But when I have it in my test, I receive the following error in karma browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:9876/base/src/node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Below is my systemjs.config, karma.config.js, karma-test-shim.js:

**systemjs.config**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-jwt': 'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
      'moment': 'npm:moment/min/moment.min.js',
      'moment-timezone': 'npm:moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**karma.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'src/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = appBase;      // app source TS files

  // Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
  var testingBase    = 'testing/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testingSrcBase = 'testing/'; // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],

    client: {
      builtPaths: [appBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js', // <-- added explicitly to see if it fixes the issue

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: appBase + '/systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '/systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js', // optionally extend SystemJS mapping e.g., with barrels

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for modules fetched by SystemJS
      '/base/src/node_modules/': '/base/node_modules/'
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

**karma-test-shim.js**

```
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

// builtPaths: root paths for output ("built") files
// get from karma.config.js, then prefix with '/base/' (default is 'src/')
var builtPaths = (__karma__.config.builtPaths || ['src/'])
                 .map(function(p) { return '/base/'+p;});

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

// Is a "built" file if is JavaScript file in one of the "built" folders
function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) &&
         builtPaths.reduce(function(keep, bp) {
           return keep || (path.substr(0, bp.length) === bp);
         }, false);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  // Base URL for System.js calls. 'base/' is where Karma serves files from.
  baseURL: 'base/src',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
    'angular2-jwt': 'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js', // <-- added explicitly to see if it fixes the issue
  },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
  .then(importSystemJsExtras)
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
function importSystemJsExtras(){
  return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
  .catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(
      'Warning: System.import could not load the optional "systemjs.config.extras.js". Did you omit it by accident? Continuing without it.'
    );
    console.log(reason);
  });
}

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

I have angular2-jwt in my packages.json dependencies and installed it already. I really don't know what the issue is.

**UPDATE:**

Ran the tests again and for no reason, this time it loads the angular2-jwt.js! But still another problem: this file has a line: require('...') so I get the following error in karma browser console this time:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  at node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing...

```
'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js'
```

... to ...

```
{ pattern: 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js', included: false, watched: false }
```

... in your karma.config.js file.

The first line of code tells Karma to use the default values for a file, which are as follows

```
{ pattern: "your/file/path", included: true, watched: false }
```

Including the file tells Karma to load the file using a script tag, which is not what you want if you're loading an application using systemjs.

I was just reading about these tricky configuration settings today. I've pasted a link to the article below if you're interested. I found it to be quite helpful.

https://psamsotha.github.io/angular/2016/12/16/angular2-testing-karma-systemjs.html

Comment: Wow! It fixed the issue. Awesome! I was really frustrated at this for days! Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it!

Comment: You are certainly welcome. Glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the appBase in karma.config.js as

```
 var appBase    = '.';       /////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Thanks @Aravind but if I do that then systemjs will fail to load.

Comment: `appSrcBase = 'src/'` try this in karmaconfig

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you please have a look at the update section?